# Multiple joins with count on a hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

So I have 4 different tables and I want to put them in one table with one of the columns from the tables and the # of times a particular value appears in that column. All the columns are strings.

For example:

```
table A
col1
20190204
20190204
20190204
20190205
20190205
20190205

Table B
col1
20200204
20200204
20200204
20200204
20200205
20200205
20200205

TableC
col1
20210204
20210204
20210204
20210204
20210205
20210205
20210205

TableD
col1
20220204
20220204
20220204
20220204
20220205
20220205
20220205

TableE -- All the 4 tables will go into here
TableE is empty and needs to be populated with the dates from the other tables and the number of times they occur in those tables. For example:
col1(tablea)    col2           col3(tbaleb)  col4     col5(tablec)    col6
20190204         4             20200204       4       20210204         4     
20190205         3             20200205       3       20210205         3    

col7(tabled)  col8
20220205       3
20220205       4 
    etc...
```

I am new to hue, so I tried something like this:

```
insert overwrite into tablee (
tablee.tablea.date, tablee.tablea.datecount,
tablee.tablebdate, tablee.tableb.datecount,
tablee.tablecdate, tablee.tablec.datecount,
tablee.tableddate, tablee.tablea.datedcount,
select tablea.date, count(tablea.date),  
tableb.date, count(tableb.date),
tablec.date, count(tablec.date),
tabled.date, count(tabled.date)
)
from tablea, tableb, tablec, tabled
left join tablee on (tablea.date=tablee.date)
left join tablee on (tableb.date=tablee.date)
left join tablee on (tablec.date=tablee.date)
left join tablee on (tabled.date=tablee.date);
```

But I am not able to get it to work correctly. Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below query gives your desired result set.

```
select * from (select col1,count(*) from tablea group by 1)a
full outer join
(select col1,count(*) from tableb group by 1)b on a.col1=b.col1
full outer join
(select col1,count(*) from tablec group by 1)c on b.col1=c.col1
full outer join
(select col1,count(*) from tabled group by 1)d on c.col1=d.col1;
```

First all the grouped data from each table is calculated and then we doing full outer join to include all values of col1 from each table to get result set. Finally if the result set is what the desired one we can convert select statement to insert into/overwrite statement.